# Time from multiple data sources

Tags: c++, time

I have a machine with a C++ project that is a socket client to another machine that is sending a timestamp, it is an unsigned int representing the number of milliseconds since midnight.

```
unsigned int time;
```

How can I compare this time value to the system time and get the spread between the two in milliseconds?  The spread should be "relatively" constant over time.

The accuracy of the system time must be within one millisecond because if the spread widens to (for example) 20 milliseconds, I know something is wrong and the code needs to be aware.

I am able to use Windows.h 
Any advice would be appreciated and sample code too!

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure that the network latency will be consistently much less than 20ms?

Comment: It might be easier to run `ntpd` on your systems; the documentation claims [It provides accuracies typically less than a millisecond on LANs and up to a few milliseconds on WANs.](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/index.html). NTP4 has been designed over the course of decades to reliably share time amongst hosts.

Comment: Simplest answer would be to configure a ntp server that synchronizes the clocks. I am not sure about the precision of the synchronization, but it should suffice.

Comment: The question is how to compare two values, the system time and the time I'm receiving, its a simple coding question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help you. I used it in a project I did in school to compare the efficiencies of several algorithms for calculating a maximum subsequence sum. This is a class that utilizes the function QueryPerformanceCounter which is included in Windows.h and I believe it to be accurate in the sub-ms range. It was the most accurate way I could figure to do it in C++ using Windows.h.

I got it from an open source project on Google Code called gpufrustrum

```
#include <windows.h>

class CPrecisionTimer
{
  LARGE_INTEGER lFreq, lStart;

public:
  CPrecisionTimer()
  {
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&lFreq);
  }

  inline void Start()
  {
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&lStart);
  }

  inline double Stop()
  {
    // Return duration in seconds...
    LARGE_INTEGER lEnd;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&lEnd);
    return (double(lEnd.QuadPart - lStart.QuadPart) / lFreq.QuadPart);
  }
};
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. As I understand it, the question is how to estimate the difference between the clocks in two different machines not how to measure local time with precision.